# How to use websocket in tauri listen event

Tags: rust, tauri

I attempted to create a websocket client in tauri to receive information and send it to the front-end application. The websocket cargo is tokio-tungstenite.but i have some problem in listen_gloabl function

Cargo.toml

```rust
serde_json = "1.0"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
tokio = { version = "1.25.0", features = ["full"] }
tauri = { version = "1.5.2", features = ["system-tray", "dialog-all", "icon-ico"] }
rodio = "0.17.3"
futures-util = { version = "0.3.28", default-features = false, features = ["sink", "std"] }
tokio-tungstenite = "0.20.1"
url = "2.3.1"
```

main.rs

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
 tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            let app_handle = app.handle();
            tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async move {
                connect_ws_async(&app_handle).await.unwrap();
            });

            Ok(())
        })
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------
async fn connect_ws_async(app_handle: &AppHandle) -> Result<()> {
    use url::Url;
    use futures_util::{StreamExt};
    use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
    use tokio_tungstenite::{connect_async, tungstenite::protocol::Message};
    use tokio::sync::Mutex;

    let url = Url::parse("ws://127.0.0.1:8084/ws").expect("bad url!");
     let (mut ws_stream, _) = connect_async(url).await.expect("Failed to connect");
    println!("WebSocket handshake has been successfully completed");

    let (mut write, mut read) = ws_stream.split();

    let mutex_write = Mutex::new(write);
    let mutex_read = Mutex::new(read);

    let handle_write = app_handle.clone();
    let handle_read = app_handle.clone();

    handle_write.listen_global("msg_send", move |event:Event| {
        let msg = event.payload().unwrap();
        block_in_place(move || {
            tauri::async_runtime::block_on(async {
                // use mutex_write to send message
            });
        });
    });

    Ok(())
}
```

i see the same question in [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-add-async-await-inside-the-listen-events-in-tauri-application/78608).
but i still have no diea.

Comment: i am looking into it

Comment: Where do you run the WS server that listens on `127.0.0.1:8084`? 
Is it inside Tauri or a separate process?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why would you want websockets in this configuration, you could perfectly use Tauri's [IPC](https://tauri.app/v1/references/architecture/inter-process-communication/) loop for this:

You could use `invoke` on the frontend side, and `listen` on both backend and frontend to exchange the events.

If you're not running your own websockets server inside the tauri, then you probably want to just use `spawn` when you process your event, instead of `block_in_place`.

```rust
tokio::spawn(async move {
  process(socket).await;
});
```

If you're looking to response from Rust to a websocket client in the frontend, then you can use [this](https://github.com/developermindsetcom/tauri-websockets/blob/master/src-tauri/src/main.rs#L66-L70):

```rust
async fn handle_connection<'a>(app_handle:tauri::AppHandle, raw_stream: TcpStream, addr: SocketAddr) {
    let peer_map:tauri::State<PeerMap> = app_handle.state();
    ...
    let ws_stream = tokio_tungstenite::accept_async(raw_stream)
        .await
        .expect("Error during the websocket handshake occurred");
    println!("WebSocket connection established: {}", addr);

    // Insert the write part of this peer to the peer map.
    let (tx, rx) = unbounded();
    peer_map.lock().unwrap().insert(addr, tx.clone());
    ...
    let broadcast_incoming = incoming.try_for_each(|msg| {
        ...
        let response = format!("Rust received \"{}\"", text);
        tx.unbounded_send(response.as_str().into()).unwrap();

        future::ok(())
    });

    let receive_from_others = rx.map(Ok).forward(outgoing);

    pin_mut!(broadcast_incoming, receive_from_others);
    future::select(broadcast_incoming, receive_from_others).await;

    println!("{} disconnected", &addr);
    peer_map.lock().unwrap().remove(&addr);
}
```

In the case you are running tungstenite server, then you can follow my other tutorial [here](https://www.developermindset.com/tauri-client-and-websockets-server/)